# Wordpress subdirectory blog pointing to separate subdomain install

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, path

I am redirecting a blog from `blog.foo.com` to a new wordpress installation on `foo.com` (root domain).

I've taken these setup steps:

1. Installed a second new wordpress instance at foo.com/new-wp
2. Moved index.php and .htaccess files from foo.com/new-wp to root foo.com
3. Updated root index.php with:

   `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/new-wp/wp-blog-header.php' );`
4. Set `WordPress Address (URL)` field to `https://foo.com/new-wp`
5. Set `Site Address (URL)` to `https://foo.com`
6. Updated foo.com/new-wp wp-config.php with

   `if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )`
       `define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-new');`
7. Left existing wordpress install at blog.foo.com
8. Set the path for the new blog on foo.com to foo.com/blog
9. Set 301 redirects for each blog.foo.com url, for example, blog.foo.com/article is redirected to foo.com/article

Everything is working as expected with the root domain (foo.com) and all of the redirected urls.

However, foo.com/blog, which should be the blog homepage subfolder on the root, when visited, doesn't display any static files because it requests blog.foo.com and includes:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://blog.foo.com/" />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//blog.foo.com' />
<link rel="pingback" href="https://blog.foo.com/xmlrpc.php">
etc.
```

Why is foo.com/blog requesting blog.foo.com? It's an entirely separate wordpress install and nothing on foo.com, foo.com/wp-new or foo.com/blog point to it.

Root foo.com htaccess:

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTPS} off
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.foo.com$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo.com$
rewriterule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/foo\.com\/$1" [R=301,L] #59ca6fd8c3abd

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

rewriterule ^index\.php$ - [L]
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
rewriterule . /index.php [L]
```

in the db for foo.com, I've searched for "%blog.foo.com%" and see this reference in wp_options table. I tried replacing 'blog.foo.com' with 'foo.com' but it did not have any effect on my issue.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `dbname`.`wp_options` 
WHERE (
   `option_id` LIKE  '%"%blog.foo.com%"%'
   OR  `option_name` LIKE CONVERT( _utf8 '%"%blog.foo.com%"%'
   USING utf8mb4 ) 
   COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
   OR  `option_value` LIKE CONVERT( _utf8 '%"%blog.foo.com%"%'
   USING utf8mb4 ) 
   COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
   OR  `autoload` LIKE CONVERT( _utf8 '%"%blog.foo.com%"%'
   USING utf8mb4 ) 
   COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
   )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: FYI, to add blocks of code, you don't need to surround each line with backticks... just indent each line by 4 spaces, or use the `{}` option from the toolbar :)

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your new install - so, its installed in a folder called "wp-new" and running from the root foo.com, so how does foo.com/blog come into it? Also, did you copy the content from the blog.foo.com database and the theme files to your new install? If so, did you replace all references to  blog.foo.com in the database? And checked just in case there are any hard-coded links in your theme files?

Comment: for the new /wp-new install I created a separate new db, exported the posts from blog.foo.com and used the wp import tool to import the new posts. I installed a new theme on /wp-new, different than blog.foo.com. I wouldn't expect there to be any references to blog.foo.com in the foo.com db since it's a different db. foo.com/blog is the url route for the blog index page on foo.com that displays all blog posts in new theme installed in /wp-new

Comment: In that case it sounds like the only place left that it could come from is the database, though I don't know why if you only imported the posts with the import tool. I'd suggest doing a full search on your new db for '%blog.foo.com%' - you can do this though MyPHPAdmin

Comment: searched the foo.com db. the references to blog.foo I see are: 1. in wp_posts table, column guid includes blog.foo for imported posts and 2. there is one reference in wp_options (included above)

Answer (score 0):

I would still be interested in a technical explanation for why `foo.com/blog` requested `blog.foo.com` despite being separate sites and db's, however, as a practical solution to the problem itself by changing the URL to `foo.com/something-other-than-just-blog` it now requests and responds with the correct `foo.com` URL.